# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL in windows phone 7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

Created a WCF service and published in IIS. I tried to access this service in windows phone7 so i implement it by installing json.net from Nuget package. Got Serialization of json in correct format.But Deserialization of json fails in webClient_OpenReadCompleted method. I given my code template here

private void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {

```
string s = e.Result.ToString();
Customer deserCustomers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(s);
int id=deserCustomers.CustomerId;
string n = deserCustomers.CustomerName;
lstCustomer.ItemsSource = deserCustomers.ToString();
```

}

While reaching the below code got exception as follows:

Customer deserializedCustomers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);

An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code.

Give me suggestions to solve this error

Comment: i my experience, the reason for this exception is mismatch of `json` field/filds, can you show us your `json` response and your class `Customer`

Comment: public class Customer
        {
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }
            public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        }

Generated Json:
[{"CustomerId":100,"CustomerName":"Cust 1"},{"CustomerId":102,"CustomerName":"Cust 2"},{"CustomerId":103,"CustomerName":"Cust 3"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is quite simple , you should  just  make your class interface of a list, because your json is array something like:

```
 public class Customer:List<object>
{        
    public int CustomerId{get; set;}        
    public string CustomerName{get; set;}
}
```

than everything is pretty basic

```
var deserCustomers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(s);
foreach (var cust in deserCustomers) 
        {
          ....
        }
```

hope it's work (:

Comment: I replaced  Customer as Customer[] in below code                    var deserCustomers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(s);     It works correctly since Result return type given in webservice is array.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Forget to write this point After removed the  List<object> from Customer Class.It works fine